# How To Create a Jquery Slider Where Left image is active

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, slider, carousel

I'm sorry for the horrible title, i can't figure out how to name this problem.

I have the following design from our team: [image]

I need to create a slider for the team members. I need for each item to be a "slide" and when you click one of the slides, that slide slides all the way to the left of the div and becomes "active" in color.

I can't figure out how i'm going to do this. My initial idea is a div with "overflow:hidden" and then have a LONG div inside that with a huge width so all the items lay out horizontally, but they are hidden. Then when you click any item, the whole unordered list shifts left or right so that the active item is aligned left in the container div.

What i guess i'm looking for is some kind of example or solution that someone has seen in the browsing of the internet that I can look at for an example or any ideas on how to accomplish this.

Comment: u could use a jquery carousel for this. There are plenty of those in the web!

Comment: problem is that most carousels (like bootstrap for instance) have 3 or 4 items in a row and you slide between the sets. I need only 1 item to be active at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem and sort of wrote a simple carousel on my own. This is just a simple one with basic functionality. Please get an idea of this and create ur own effect to match your needs. What I've done is used jquery and wrote a simple plugin which would accept a main element containing an unorderd list.

The plugin goes like this.

```
(function($){
$.fn.carousel = function(){
    var item = this;
    this.css({
        'position':'relative'
    });
    this.find('.back').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':'50%',
        'left':'0px',
        'color':'#fff',
        'z-index':'2'
    });
    this.find('.next').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':'50%',
        'right':'0px',
        'color':'#fff',
        'z-index':'2'
    });
    this.find('ul').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':'0px'
    })
    this.find('.next').click(function(){
        if($('li:last-child').hasClass('active')){
            $('li:last-child').removeClass('active')
            $('li').first().addClass('active');
            item.find('ul').animate({'left': '0px'},1000)
            return false;
        }
        $('li.active').next().addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
        item.find('ul').animate({'left': '-=205'},1000)
    });
    this.find('.back').click(function(){
        if($('li').first().hasClass('active')){
            $('li').first().removeClass('active')
            $('li:last-child').addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
        $('li.active').prev().addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
        item.find('ul').animate({'left': '+=205'},1000)
    });
}
}(jQuery));
```

The implementation could be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1hc1rybd/)

**Please mind that the functionality is basic and you would have to improve the code.**